# Schedule push notification in lambda aws at regular interval

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, push-notification

I want to trigger a push notification from the backend at regular intervals. What is the best way to do that? I am thinking to have a cron expression that I will schedule for every minute. I am working on stock app and I need to send a notification to the user about the stock rising or declining. I have integrated frontend & backend with a notification that is a trigger from the client-side. But I need to trigger it from backend without client-side being triggering it every second as it will affect performance.

My applications are in react, node, and AWS lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Lambda event does not need information from the backend (i.e. it could do its own lookups) then you could schedule it to be invoked once a minute via a CloudWatch Event used a [schedule expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html).

**If** however the Lambda requires the existing script to run as is, but on a schedule then you would be looking at using cron for it.

Answer (score 2):

You can schedule AWS Lambda execution using CloudWatch Events:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Serverless architecture you should consider using [SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/?whats-new-cards.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cards.sort-order=desc). You can set Lambda function to track SNS event as a callback.

If you do have some backend server in NodeJS you might want to use a [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) connection. In this case either interval or CRON job would be fine.

Comment: SNS would need to be trigger from the backend. I need application to check at regular interval and send notification

Comment: Then probably the answer by Chris Williams is the most suitable. Because, schedule expression is the same cron job that you were looking for at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

One interesting option is to use  Cloud Watch Events pushing data into SNS .

IOT Core subscribing and  listening to the same SNS topic via SDK . More details on the below post .

"The SDK automatically manages the WebSocket connection and also handles many common connectivity issues in web apps. The messages are categorized using topics, which are strings defining channels of messages.

The AWS IoT Core service manages broadcasts between backend publishers and frontend subscribers. This enables fan-out functionality, which occurs when multiple subscribers are listening to the same topic. You can broadcast messages to thousands of frontend devices using this mechanism. For web application integration, this is the preferable way to implement publish-subscribe than using Amazon SNS."

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/managing-backend-requests-and-frontend-notifications-in-serverless-web-apps/

Comment: I need to trigger at regular intervals like every 20 seconds. I am using service worker for push notification. Do I need to use IoT as well now or will it improve performance?

Comment: With IOT Core , it takes care of managing persistant connection with the front end applications . Let's say 1000 clients are connected  and listening to SNS topic  , you can fan out the notification from SNS  easily to all these clients without getting overwhelmed with managing websockets and clients .